# WSO2 DAS does not suport Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-das

I'm using API manager 1.10.0 and DAS 3.0.1.

I'm trying to setup Postgres for DAS. There is no `postpresql.sql`, so I used `oracle.sql`.

But I get exception.

```
[2016-08-11 15:06:25,079] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter} -  Error in executing task: Don't know how to save StructField(max_request_time,DecimalType(30,0),true) to JDBC
java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't know how to save StructField(max_request_time,DecimalType(30,0),true) to JDBC
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.carbon.JDBCRelation.insert(JDBCRelation.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoDataSource.run(commands.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:950)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:950)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:755)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQueryLocal(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQuery(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:709)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeQuery(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:201)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeScript(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:151)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask.execute(AnalyticsTask.java:59)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to save StructField(max_request_time,DecimalType(30,0),true) to JDBC
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.carbon.package$JDBCWriteDetails$$anonfun$schemaString$1$$anonfun$2.apply(carbon.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.carbon.package$JDBCWriteDetails$$anonfun$schemaString$1$$anonfun$2.apply(carbon.scala:42)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.carbon.package$JDBCWriteDetails$$anonfun$schemaString$1.apply(carbon.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.carbon.package$JDBCWriteDetails$$anonfun$schemaString$1.apply(carbon.scala:38)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.carbon.package$JDBCWriteDetails$.schemaString(carbon.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.carbon.JDBCRelation.insert(JDBCRelation.scala:180)
        ... 26 more
```

Create table for API_REQUEST_SUMMARY script is:

```
CREATE TABLE API_REQUEST_SUMMARY ( 
api character varying(100)
, api_version character varying(100)
, version character varying(100)
, apiPublisher character varying(100)
, consumerKey character varying(100)
, userId character varying(100)
, context character varying(100)
, max_request_time decimal(30)
, total_request_count integer
, hostName character varying(100)
, year SMALLINT
, month SMALLINT
, day SMALLINT
, time character varying(30)
, PRIMARY KEY(api,api_version,apiPublisher,consumerKey,userId,context,hostName,time)
);
```

How to make this work with Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define the column `max_request_time` as `bigint`